# Como fazer JOIN em 4 tabelas ou mais?

Tags: mysql, query

Preciso fazer um select em quatro tabelas mas estou tendo dor de cabeça com isso, segue a imagem de como elas estão relacionadas: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seria algo como :

```
SELECT integrantes.id_integrante,
       integrantes_documento.nome_integrante,
       integrantes_endereco.cep_integrante,
       votos_uniforme.voto_uniforme1,
       votos_uniforme.voto_uniforme2,
       votos_uniforme.voto_uniforme3
  FROM integrante
```

Só falta os JOIN'S, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Quais campos você precisa que sejam listados?

Comment: O join em tese, não muda, tu só vai colocando

JOIN tabela (tbl_select.id = tbl_join.id)...

Comment: Coloquei na citação do SELECT quais seriam os campos, teria como dar um exemplo ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É só usar o INNER JOIN (ou LEFT JOIN)

```
SELECT integrantes.id_integrante, integrantes_documento.nome_integrante, 
  integrantes_endereco.cep_integrante, votos_uniforme.voto_uniforme1, 
  votos_uniforme.voto_uniforme2, votos_uniforme.voto_uniforme3 
FROM integrantes 
inner join integrantes_contato
  on integrantes_contato.id_integrante = integrante.id_integrante
inner join integrantes_documento
  on integrantes_documento.id_integrante = integrante.id_integrante
inner join integrantes_endereco
  on integrantes_endereco.id_integrante = integrante.id_integrante
inner join votos_uniforme
  on votos_uniforme.id_integrante = integrante.id_integrante
```

Comment: Ele mostra esse error: #1054 - Coluna 'integrante.id_integrante' desconhecida em 'on clause'

Comment: altera seu integrante para o nome certo da tabela ou seja integrantes em todas os on

Comment: Funcionou aqui, obrigado